# Bitbucket issue kind: enhancement vs. task

Tags: bitbucket

short question: What is the difference between *tasks* and *enhancements* in Bitbucket issue tracker? Any thumb rules, best practices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A task is a generic label for some development activity, whereas an enhancement is quite clear in how it should be used e.g. refining the user experience, optimisations, etc.

I believe you could have as a task something such as "document x".